# How to get next page from API resource link

Tags: api, asynchronous, iterator, recursive-query

I currently hit this problem:

I made a request to a resource and received: 30,000 hits. The
response looks like so:

```
{
 totalRecords: 30,000,
 data: [{...}],
 links: {
   selfLink: 'http://example-api.com/data?api_key&page=0&size=10',
   nextLink: 'http://example-api.com/data?api_key&page=1&size=10',
 }
}
```

Question: How do i recursively get nextLink to retrieve next page (all), until the last page of data using javascript/node?

Any Insight, ideas, solutions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code below sould work, as long as the api is well implemented and there is no next link when you finish iterating.

```
url = 'http://example-api.com/data?api_key&page=0&size=10' # your first request url
data = [] # declare variable to hold the api data
    
    # keep calling the api while there is a url
    while url:
        print(f'getting request: {url}\n')
        response = requests.get(url=url)
        url = response['links'].get('nextLink') if response['links'].get('nextLink') else None
        data.extend(response.json()['data']) # add the response to data
```